# What is a proper way to store drawables in the Room Library? Android, Kotlin, XML

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, mobile-development

I'm beginner in Android development and now developing [my application](https://github.com/ksairos/Personal-Finances-App) that helps me to keep track of my personal finances. All my categories (food, shopping, etc) have a displayed color and icon (XML drawable) that should be stored inside Room database:
[image: Category example]

What datatype or method should I use in order to store those icons inside my Room database?

This is my current implementation of the Category Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "category")
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    var name: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "expanses")
    var expanses: Double?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "icon")
    var icon: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "color")
    var color: Int?)
```

I'm using [this Icon Picker](https://github.com/maltaisn/icondialoglib) in my app.

Comment: As i can see , it is icons you can do one thing just save there reference in room database and set it from resource whenever you set it

Comment: Why do you need to store it though? Just create a function that takes Category as input and it returns corresponding resource/drawable.

Comment: @TheLibrarian the problem was to find and "return corresponding resource/drawable". For that I wanted to store whole icons inside the database for each corresponding category, but now switched to using methods in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone, who are interested, here is my own solutions:

1. Instead of storing icons as Bitmap or using any other type converters, I can store the names of my `Drawables` inside my database and use `resources.getIdentifier("myIconName", "drawable", Context.packageName)` in order to retrieve them whenever I want. More information in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/vwkyce/storing_drawable_ids_in_room_database/)
2. As I use [this Icon Picker](https://github.com/maltaisn/icondialoglib), I can instead store icon IDs (do not confuse with `resource ID`), which I specify inside `icons.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<icons width="24" height="24" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<category id="0" name="category_shapes">
    <icon id="0" tags="shape,circle" path="M12 2A10 10 0 0 0 2 12A10 10 0 0 0 12 22A10 10 0 0 0 22 12A10 10 0 0 0 12 2Z"/>
    <icon id="1" tags="shape,triangle,three" path="M1 21H23L12 2"/>
    <icon id="2" tags="shape,square,four" path="M3 3V21H21V3"/>
    <icon id="3" tags="shape,pentagon,five" path="M12 2.5L2 9.8L5.8 21.5H18.2L22 9.8L12 2.5Z"/>
    <icon id="4" tags="shape,octagon,eight" path="M15.73 3H8.27L3 8.27V15.73L8.27 21H15.73L21 15.73V8.27"/>
</category>
<category id="1" name="category_stars">
    <icon id="5" tags="shape,star,three" path="M12 2.6L9 12.4L2 19.9L12 17.6L22 20L15 12.5L12 2.6Z"/>
    <icon id="6" tags="shape,star,four" path="M12 1L9 9L1 12L9 15L12 23L15 15L23 12L15 9L12 1Z"/>
    <icon id="7" tags="shape,star,five" path="M12 17.27L18.18 21L16.54 13.97L22 9.24L14.81 8.62L12 2L9.19 8.62L2 9.24L7.45 13.97L5.82 21L12 17.27Z"/>
    <icon id="8" tags="shape,star,eight" path="M2.2 16.06L3.88 12L2.2 7.94L6.26 6.26L7.94 2.2L12 3.88L16.06 2.2L17.74 6.26L21.8 7.94L20.12 12L21.8 16.06L17.74 17.74L16.06 21.8L12 20.12L7.94 21.8L6.26 17.74L2.2 16.06Z"/>
</category>
</icons>
```